# Soap array object in PHP. Where does the data end up in the SOAP request

Tags: c#, php, apache, soap

I'm trying to call a SOAP service from C#. Unfortunately the way it's been implemented in PHP is a bit baffling to me. I've been given this code here in PHP explaining how to call the service:

```
    $oClient = new SoapClient("http://xxxxxxxxx?wsdl",
array(
    'trace'         => 1, 
    'exceptions'    => true,
    'login'         => "xxxxxxxx",
    'password'      => "xxxxxxxx"       
    ));
```

The trouble is that I have no idea how to pass the array in c# or what the formatted message looks like.

I would like to know how PHP inserts this information into the SOAP request. I got the guy to remove security for a few moments to see if my message was formatted right and everything works fine that I've written to process the request apart from this custom array object.

I tried building a linux machine to monitor the output but I can't get linux running on my machine for some reason as it green screens and I really need to get this done quick as I've wasted ages on this now.

I think this information must appear in the header of the SOAP request but documentation seems scarce. I've never really liked the documentation for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what are you trying to do? The PHP code you provided constructs SOAP client for SOAP service based on WSDL (Web Service Description Language) description at http://xxxxxxxxx?wsdl , it does not call anything. You call various functions described in WSDL like this:

```
$oClient->__soapCall("SomeFunction", array($a, $b, $c));
```

where "SomeFunction" is a name of remote function and array is its parameters.

Anyway, it seems like you are trying to build a SOAP client on C# - there should be a C# library or extension for that, so calling a SOAP service should not be much different from PHP. Basically, you just construct a client and call remote functions, which are (and their parameters) described in WSDL file. You should not even see XML packets.

If you'd like to see some examples how do packets look like, here's one: [Annotated WSDL Examples @w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/2001/03/14-annotated-WSDL-examples)

And some description: [Using WSDL in SOAP applications @ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soap/)

But its all is taken care by library in your language of choice. There is a discussion here at stackoverflow: [Which C# SOAP Client Library is easiest to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/963794/which-c-sharp-soap-client-library-is-easiest-to-use)

Comment: I usually just use a web reference but it doesn't really have an array object like in apache. I suppose I am going to have to bite the bullet and learn WCF

Comment: Actually, I've just realised. The array must be sent at some point because it contains information required by the SOAP service so surely it must appear in the SOAP packet in some form or another or does it get sent in the http response when the client starts talking to the service

Comment: I obviously call the web reference with a method later. the webreference that was autogenerated by .net generates method stubs which I call. I've tried calling these and I get a username and password not recognised because the credentials are stored in the array that you place in the SOAPClient when instantiating it in PHP. The SoapClient in .net doesn't seem to have anything like the PHP one. Hence I've been trying to find out at a low level how the array is passed in PHP

Comment: SOAP services usually use HTTP authentication, so there is no array of arguments at that point. After the client is authenticated, when calling a remote method, array of arguments is sent inside a SOAP packet which is transported over HTTP. SOAP is a protocol itself, HTTP is just a transport. SOAP XML packets can be sent over any other protocol, like SMTP, UDP or AMQP.

Comment: These links may help you: [Web Services C Sharp .NET End to End Tutorial](http://wiki.service-now.com/index.php?title=Web_Services_C_Sharp_.NET_End_to_End_Tutorial), [How to: Add Security Credentials to a SOAP Message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms819938.aspx), [HTTP Authentication with Web References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923015/http-authentication-with-web-references)

Comment: Thanks sniff for all your effort here sniff. You plucky helpers are definitely appreciated. Unfortunately I don't think the problem is service credentials, the array sent to PHP is actually a custom header of some kind. It is literally somehow customised on the server at their end. These aren't network credentials they are somehow read by the service. I had already tried all that stuff but I still can't work out how to send that array.

Comment: Thanks again Sniff, finally got this working. Had to go and do something else for a while. But eventually I got it working with the article you linked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923015/http-authentication-with-web-references I don't know what was wrong the last time I tried this but a load of tweaking and wireshark eventually got me there